# sshuttle connection timing out

Tags: centos, ssh, networking, ssh-tunneling

I have a local server that only allows connections within the internal network. I have another server inside the internal network that can connect to outside the network. I want to use the second server as a tunnel for the first, so I can get outside connections with the first.

I can `ssh` to the second server just fine. However, when I run:

```
sudo sshuttle -r myuser@myserver 0/0 -vv
```

and then type in my local password, and then my remote password, it just hangs indefinitely, and no connections on the server can get out. Again, I can do `ssh myuser@myserver` just fine.

Any suggestions for debugging this? I'm on CentOS 7.

Comment: Is your `myuser` able to create `tun` devices (e.g. `root`?).

Comment: @Jakuje What would be the quickest way to test that?

Comment: If the `myuser` is not root, it probably does not have these permissions. You can try it with pure `ssh` using `ssh -vvv -w 0:0 myuser@myserver`, which should yell some errors.

Comment: You were right - sshuttle works when I ssh in as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `sshuttle` working, you need a superuser privileges on both client and server (to create `tun` devices on both ends). This is not possible with normal (`myuser`) users.

This should work with `root` user, if he is allowed to log in. This is generally not a good idea to allow root logins, so restricting this user to public key authentication (`PasswordAuthentication no`) or prevent running commands (`ForceCommand /usr/sbin/nologin`) s also good idea, but securing the server is obviously not the part of this question.

Comment: Is it still a bad idea to have root access to a server via SSH, if SSH connections are only allowed when they are coming from the internal network?

Comment: If you have a filter only for internal network, it is quite fine, if the network is trusted.

Comment: just read the question. Makes sense.